# Apply a filter in the display of a jsp table

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

Sorry in advance if I messed up. This is my first post here and English is not my native language.

I'm writing a modal in a webapp that needs to display the move history of a product.  Previously, the application receives the history through an HttpServletRequest in java.

When clicking on a button, the modal is displayed.

My problem is that I am unable to filter the list in the display.

Here is the jsp code that contains the button as well as the constraint for the filter:  `data-noRefALivrer="${listeProduitsFinis.refALivrer}"`

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="inputCurrentRefALivrer">
...
<c:forEach var="listeProduitsFinis" items="${LISTPRODUITFINI}">
                <tr class="trProduitFini" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-id="${listeProduitsFinis.detCmd}"
                    data-noCmd="${listeProduitsFinis.cmd}"
                    data-noDetCmd="${listeProduitsFinis.detCmd}"
                    data-noRefALivrer="${listeProduitsFinis.refALivrer}">
                    <td style="font-size: 18px;" class="text-center" id="detCMDID">${listeProduitsFinis.detCmd}</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 18px;" class="text-center">${listeProduitsFinis.refALivrer}</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 18px;" class="text-center">${listeProduitsFinis.location}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
                            style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
                            <span style="font-size: 1.5em; color: white"
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">
                                </span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
...
```

Here is the javascript code associated with the jsp file and the modal

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
...
$(".table").delegate('tbody tr', 'click', function(e)
    {
        var trToUse = $(e.target).closest('tr');
        var noRefALivrer = trToUse.attr('data-noRefALivrer')
        e.preventDefault();

        if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON' || e.target.tagName == 'SPAN')     
        {
            $("#inputCurrentRefALivrer").attr('value', noRefALivrer);
            $("#titreh4").text("Historique de " + noRefALivrer);
            $("#modalAfficherHistorique").modal()           
        }
        else
        {
            $("#modalAfficherImage").modal()
        }
    });
...
}
```

Again "refALivrer" is the main constraint to filter the history.

Finally, here is the jsp code of the modal (in a separate file)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<div id="modalAfficherHistorique" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: red">    
                    
                <h4 id="titreh4" class="modal-title text-center"></h4>
                
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="text-center">DE</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="text-center">À</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="text-center">DATE</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="text-center">QUI</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="text-center">QUOI</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="listeHistorique" items="${LISTHISTORIQUE}">     
                            <c:if test="${listeHistorique.refALivrer == param.inputCurrentRefALivrer}">
                            
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 10px;" class="text-center">${listeHistorique.oldLocation}</td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 10px;" class="text-center">${listeHistorique.newLocation}</td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 10px;" class="text-center">${listeHistorique.date}</td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 10px;" class="text-center">${listeHistorique.user}</td>
                                    <td style="font-size: 10px;" class="text-center">${listeHistorique.operation}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:if>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: red">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the h4 tag does indeed display the "refALivrer"

Also note that if I remove the "c:if", the history is displayed correctly, but without a filter.

TY all for your help!